# Most frequent value in table PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a table called referee with two columns: refereeID and name. I want to query the most common name (from referee) that appears in a table called fixtureDetails(linked by foreign key refereeID) and echo the result of the query.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write free code for you. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you want. Can you post your sample tables and the results that you are expecting. Also, post the SQL code that you tried.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you'll need an if, else statement some other form of PHP control codes to determine the name with the highest value and you echo. You can also check the [PHP.net website](http://php.net/) for more help.